# Combine objects in 2 different arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have 2 javascript requests that give back results in an array of objects.

The first object looks like this:

```
[Object {user_id="6", meta_value="5", user_nicename="richbai90", more...}, 
Object {user_id="7", meta_value="1", user_nicename="testing123", more...}]
```

the 2nd looks like this

```
[Object { usr="6", score="1 / 1", quiz_id="1"}, 
Object { usr="7", score="1 / 1", quiz_id="1"}, 
Object { usr="7", score="1/5", quiz_id="3"}]
```

Array 2 is the details of array one

What I need is a way to relate these together in javascript so that I can put the information from object 2 in the document where it needs to correspond with the information from object one.  The easiest way I could think to do this would be to combine the arrays where the user ids were the same but this appears to be more difficult then I first thought.  Here was my initial approach:

```
       $.post(AjaxRequest.ajaxurl, {
 action: "get_data"
})
 .done(function (json) {

 console.log(json);
 var data = json;


 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     if (AjaxRequest.user_ID == json[i].user_id && json[i].Quizes == "1") {
         $("#result_list").append("you have taken " + json[i].Quizes + " quiz");
     } else if (AjaxRequest.user_id == json[i].user_id && json[i].Quizes != "1") {
         $("#result_list").append("you have taken " + json[i].Quizes + " quizzes");
     } else {
         $("#result_list").append(json[i].user_nicename + " has taken " + json[i].Quizes + " quizzes" + "<br>");
     }

 }



 getDetails(json);






})

 .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
 var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
 console.log('1st Request Failed: ' + err);
});




function getDetails(data) {

 $.post(AjaxRequest.ajaxurl, {
     action: "get_details"

 })
     .done(function (details) {

     console.log(data);
     console.log(details);

     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         for (var i2 = 0; i2 < details.length; i++) {
             while (details[i2].usr == data[i].user_id) {
                 console.log(details[i2]);
                 break;
             }
         }


     }




     $("#loading").fadeOut('fast', function () {
         $("#result_list").fadeIn('fast');
     });

 })

     .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
     var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
     console.log('2nd Request Failed: ' + err);
 });


}
```

In this code block is where the work is happening

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         for (var i2 = 0; i2 < details.length; i++) {
             while (details[i2].usr == data[i].user_id) {
                 console.log(details[i2]);
                 break;
             }
         }


     }
```

The issue is that once the while loop breaks it doesn't seem to go to the next itteration of the for loop as I would have expected instead data[i] gets undefined.  If I remove the break; then data[i] is always == details[i2] and thus crashes the browser.

Maybe I'm making it harder than it needs to be?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question right - but why don't you just use a two-dimensional array?

Comment: I guess I could just combine the arrays in php before I ever send the result and that would be a lot easier.  Sorry for making this harder then it should be, but if you post an answer I'll +1 for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: 2 dimensional arrays in javascript are most of the time a waste of time, object are generally better suited.

Comment: @KKetch: unless you like [].map/[].filter/[].reduce, in which case you'll find yourself converting objects to arrays just-in-time to do everything...

Comment: @dandavis Yes javascript doesn't have, map/reduce & cie on object, but I don't see why objects have to be converted to array to crawl them, `for (var key in object) {}`should be enough

Comment: @KKetch: loops work, but array methods let you recycle logic.